# How could i detect info for the front most window in X?

Tags: x11

Is there a way to find the id and maybe the path or the type(browser, ...) of the front most window in X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the window ID, try:

```
xprop -root|grep "_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW): window id"
```

[Window properties](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html):

> _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING has bottom-to-top stacking order

One way to accomplish this is to parse the output of this command inside your application. The topmost window is the last on the list.

**EDIT:**

If you need to retrieve the process ID from the window ID, there's a small application [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/devel@xfree86.org/msg05809.html) that shows how to do this trick. I successfully compiled it with:

`g++ win_procid.cpp -o win_procid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libgtop-2.0 -lXtst -lgtop-2.0`

I had to install the package *libgtop2-dev* because I didn't have it on my system.

Comment: I just found this thread, it might be an interesting reading for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2041532/176769

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish the first "normal" window(i don't know how to say it, meaning a window that does not belong to a browser or other application.In mac it's Finder's window)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But from the process ID you can grab the process name and do this checking yourself. If process name == browser's name, then ignore this PID and get the next one from the list.

Comment: This thread might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967/how-do-i-keep-track-of-related-windows-in-x11/61144#61144